# Passing special characters in SharePoint Powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to add "Français" to search scope form the power shell to perform this task I'm using the xml to pass the values. But after it is added to the scope "Français"  looks like "FranÃ§ais". the character "ç" had converted to "Ã§"

Comment: What is the encoding of your XML?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  "encoding="utf-8"

Answer (score 3):

I have fixed my issue.

Earlier I was retrieve XML  data using power-shell without any encoding method as follows

```
Get-Content "$ScriptsFolder\SearchScopes.xml"
```

therefore I have added the `-encoding utf8` then scipt shows as follows

```
Get-Content "$ScriptsFolder\SearchScopes.xml" -encoding utf8
```

Comment: The fix did not work. I have characters like ' which when added to list using Powershell, get saved as '&#39;'.
If there is a space, it gets saved as &nbsp;
I have converted an excel to XML and then reading from this XML using Powershell script, in order to write to a SharePoint 2013 list. Let me what is the possible solution.

Comment: Make sure your Excel worksheet is saved in UTF-8 (open it in Notepad++ and select Convert to UFT-8)